# vim plugins for bash edit

Tags: shell, vim

I want to write bash in a comfortable environment.

I've tried http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=365

But it lacks:

1. function list
2. function parameter hint
3. function description hint

Is there any vim plugin which you use when writing shell script?

Comment: "comfortable" is _very_ subjective. Tool recommendations are off-topic here, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that Vim is *not an IDE* (though through its great integration capabilities and plugins, it can appear like one). It is first and foremost a (very powerful) text editor. (There are various blog posts and discussions around that topic, so I spare you further arguments.)

How are function parameter hints supposed to work in Bash scripts? Arguments are simply passed as positional untyped parameters `$1` etc., and must be parsed and assigned to variables inside the function.

Likewise, a function description would require some sort of commenting conventions (e.g. tags like *Doxygen* or *Javadoc* use); this is not generally used, so don't expect an existing solution.

Comment: For C/C++/Go, vim has some useful plugin to quick jump between function declare place and use places.  And some other useful plugin to trace the code.  But, I found I lack such information about 'shell script programming'.  And this question is not easy to google. I've showed my google result.  I'm wonder what's the experts   tool.

I agree shell's parameter is just $1,$2,... But, if the plugin provide some standard method (maybe doxygen), it could provide such function.

When tracing a long script, I think a proper utility is useful.